# Notification to adjacent widget

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that contains a "save" button. After pressing that button several other widgets (not only ancestor ones) must save its state to the file. I don't know how to inform them. What is the best way to achieve that in flutter? I was thinking about using `Notification` in the "save" widget, closest shared ancestor would contain a `NotificationListener` that triggers an event to which every widget will subscribe. For me, it doesn't look like a solution.

Comment: This might help you out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540694/how-to-save-my-current-state-by-using-json-or-something-else-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider is the recommended way to do State Management for apps of all sizes. -–Chris Sells – Product Manager, Flutter. June 19, 2019

It's pretty complicated at first, best to check out [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

The `ChangeNotifier` uses the `notifyListeners` function whenever there is any change in the class:

```
class ChangeNotifierModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String stringThatChanges = 'startValue';

  void changeTheString(String value) {
    stringThatChanges = value;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The only code that is specific to `ChangeNotifier` is the call to `notifyListeners()`. Call this method any time the model changes in a way that might change your app’s UI.

I'm pretty new to Flutter myself, but the way I understand it so, it kinda acts like a wrapper, e.g. wrapping the child of main.dart

```
MultiProvider(
   providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SingleNotifier())
   ],
   child: MyApp(),
));
```

don't forget the dependencies

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
```